# Web Analytics in Central Admin not showing all data

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-analytics

I did a full Farm restore about 2 months ago since we were moving to a new AD Forest and to new hardware and now my Web Analytic reports in Central Admin and the Site Collections only shows data going back to that date. However when I check the Analysis Reporting database I can see the data in there dating back to when I first created the farm, 01/09/2011. Has anyone seen this before? Is there a trick to get all the data to show properly in Central Admin?

Comment: None of these have fixed my issue. I do see Web Analytic information, but only since I did a restore. So the Service Application is working, I just cant see any data from before then.

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN Technet article ["Move all databases"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx), the SharePoint Web Analytics feature relies on SQL Server service broker to function. The SQL Server service broker cannot be started manually. A SharePoint timer job runs one time per day to ensure that SQL Server service broker is enabled on the necessary databases. After moving databases, you should manually run the health rule "Web Analytics: Verifies that the SQL Server Service Broker is enabled for the Web Analytics staging databases."

Would suggest you to check if SQL Server service broker works well for the WA staging and WA reporting DB. More information is [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/sharepoint2010setup/thread/30d11d27-6708-4bfe-a7d3-4b0aed522e7d).